# IDA Debug DLL with non exported function

Tags: ida, debugging

I am trying to debug a dll by IDA but it have no exported functions so I can not use rundll32.exe to debug it. How can i do that?

Thanks so much./[image]

Comment: Just read the assembly...? /// What are you trying to do? It's a DLL so you can't run it directly anyway.

Comment: If you got an answer you may want to consider posting a solution or accepting one of the posted answers.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can still execute `rundll32.exe` without an exported function by just specifying `rundll32.exe <dllpath>,` (don't forget the comma). If I'm not mistaken this will load the DLL and execute the entry point.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried before but a problem has occurred: "The instruction at 0x75DAEA5C referenced memory at 0xC. the memory could not be read -> 0000000C (exc.code c0000005, tid 1444)"
Do you know why?

Comment: I guess that's because there's an access violation within the executable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `regsvr32.exe`. It will load the DLL (run the entry point) and then silently fail because there is no `DllRegisterServer` export.

Comment: Nice. I will try

Answer (score 1):

Implement the C application which loads your library, i.e. calls `LoadLibrary()`.